# Setting up a multiplayer rpg map in Unity

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

I am wanting to make a small online based RPG game in Unity, something very small and nothing special just to learn the ropes with Networking.  My question is from a design perspective, should I create all my towns, hunting areas, dungeons and pretty much anything that would of been its own scene in a single-player game in 1 gigantic scene and just position them in a way that they are no where near each other?

Would this be "over the top" for a network to handle having everything running even if there are no players in said area like DungeonA?  Would what I put up top be correct if I had some markers in place that would set certain areas like DungeonA inactive if there are no players in DungeonA?

I hate for this question to come off as a "How you do it globally for all network games in Unity" but if anyone has any experience in something such as this please let me know if you can what works really well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will depend on how well you can break down the world you'd like to create into small environmental components. For an interconnected system of dungeons, buildings, and cities (Think older *Zelda* games) separate scenes are appropriate.  You can load/unload between each one since you don't need to see what's in a place until you go to that place. For a more open-world style (think *Skyrim* or *Ghost Recon: Wildlands*), Unity's concept of *Scenes* breaks down. The "*Scene*" paradigm employed by Unity assumes that a "*Scene*" is meant to contain some confined, definite world space. From the [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingScenes.html):

> Think of each unique Scene file as a unique level. In each Scene, you
>   will place your environments, obstacles, and decorations, essentially
>   designing and building your game in pieces.

When you load a `Scene` object, you load everything in that `Scene` and this makes it inappropriate for an open-world experience. The correct way to go about this issue (by "correct" I mean the only way it'll be performant) would be to dynamically load the assets/environment close to the player.  Your in-game "*Scene*" (as far as the .unity asset is concerned) would be void of all environmental objects and assets and load in a manner similar to this:

- A `LoadScene` occurs and the player enters the *game world* via a menu (or whatever the face of your game looks like).
- The last location of the player is retrieved (or a spawn point is determined).
- Environment geometry and assets within a certain distance are loaded into place.
- Nearby-player information is retrieved and have their visual representation instantiated.

As the player moves around, nearby environment assets (as well as other players) can be loaded piece by piece while far-away stuff is unloaded.  [LOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail) can and should be utilized.

---

In case it doesn't go without saying, you say a "small online based RPG" and that could mean it's small enough to load the *game world* at once. Understand that the limitations are mostly going to be set by the player's computer. When you're writing a networked game, the only things that need to be synchronized between players are dynamic objects (things that move and are intractable).  This means that *a bigger world wont* cause more trouble for network traffic; more stuff *moving around* and *being interacted* with *will*.

Comment: +1 for a complete answer, but you're wrong. Small sub-scenes can be loaded on top of each other to create a huge world. Think unreal 3's LevelStreamingVolumes (if memory serves).

Comment: @Arshia001 I don't see how it's "wrong." 1) My described solution is _exactly_ what Unreal does with Level Streaming Volumes and 2) This was a question regarding Unity3d, an engine that _does not_ provide that tech out of the box; I wasn't just gonna say "Go use Unreal."

Comment: @GuntherFox Thank you once again for the help Gunther on my issue.  I really do appreciate the detailed response as you have helped me with networking questions before in Unity so I cannot thank you enough for taking the time to help!

Comment: @JoeyL Hey, it's you again!  Always happy to help; hope the project's coming along nicely :D

Comment: You say "For a more open-world style (think Skyrim or Ghost Recon: Wildlands), _Unity's concept of Scenes breaks down._" This is wrong. Unity supports additive loading of sub-scenes in the same way UE does, except it's handled in code via Application.LoadLevelAdditive (which has apparently been moved to the new SceneManager class recently). You can have as many sub-scenes loading and unloading in the background as you like.

Comment: @Arshia001 They are two different features. Unreal's LSVolumes allow you to separate a level into separate volumes and the engine will handle the streaming in/out of data accordingly. It's a feature provided by the engine that only needs to be configured by the developer. Unity's additive scene loading (now part of `SceneManager.LoadScene`) allows you to load a _.unity_ file as a collection of `GameObjects` into the current heirarchy. If the developer uses this tech, they still have to implement the locating and asset-to-load determination (all the stuff my answer explains) themselves.

Comment: Enlighten me, how is creating a trigger which loads a scene when it is entered and unloads it when it is exited different from LSVolumes?

Comment: @Arshia001 1) Unreal provides the functionality _for_ the game dev. In Unity, that would be implemented by scratch _by_ the game dev. 2) LSV's can all exist in a single persistent representation of a Level. Utilizing unity's additive scene loading would require a dev to create their single "Level" across multiple scene files and would have to stitch it together themseles (this processes is a nightmare). 3) An Unreal dev can click _Window > Levels > Add Existing_ to add sub-levels together. A Unity dev would have to write their own tech/tools for editing in this manner.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that Unreal provides better tools for the job. To that, I agree. Hasn't this __always__ been the case though? Unreal provides every tool you need to build your game, Unity provides only the most basic tools and leaves the rest to developers. Hell, it's the same with Unreal's material editor and Unity's shaderlab scripts, it doesn't get much worse than that. It doesn't mean that Unity doesn't __support__ the same operations, it just takes more effort, which is kinda obvious when you compare the price tags.